# How can I set custom document table row height with apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I am trying with following code to set custom row height but it never gets applied. Document 'Test report' has 1 row and that row have default height. What's the problem?

```
  var targetDoc = DocumentApp.create('Test report');
  var body = targetDoc.getBody();
  body.setAttributes({MARGIN_LEFT: 15,
                      MARGIN_RIGHT: 15,
                      MARGIN_TOP: 15,
                      MARGIN_BOTTOM: 15,
                      PAGE_WIDTH: 595,
                      PAGE_HEIGHT: 842});

  var t1 = body.appendTable([['1','2','3','4']]);
  t1.setBorderColor('#FFFFFF');
  var attrs = {};
  attrs[DocumentApp.Attribute.MINIMUM_HEIGHT] = 35;
  t1.setAttributes(attrs);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please reffer to the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/):

`MINIMUM_HEIGHT Enum    The minimum height setting in points, for table row elements.`

In your code you are setting this as a `Table` property. You need to do this instead `t1.getRow(0).setMinimumHeight(35);`. So a working code would look like this:

```
function test() {
  var targetDoc = DocumentApp.create('Test report');
  var body = targetDoc.getBody();
  body.setAttributes({MARGIN_LEFT: 15,
                      MARGIN_RIGHT: 15,
                      MARGIN_TOP: 15,
                      MARGIN_BOTTOM: 15,
                      PAGE_WIDTH: 595,
                      PAGE_HEIGHT: 842});

  var t1 = body.appendTable([['1','2','3','4']]);
  t1.setBorderColor('#FFFFFF');
  t1.getRow(0).setMinimumHeight(35);

  return;
}
```

Note that you are setting the height in points, not centimeters or whatever else the table properties will show on the doc!

Comment: Tried with following code:
   var t1 = body.appendTable([['1','2','3','4']]);
    t1.setBorderColor('#FFFFFF');
    r1 = t1.appendTableRow();
    r1.appendTableCell('a');
    r1.appendTableCell('s');
    r1.appendTableCell('d');
    r1.appendTableCell('f');

    t1.getRow(0).setMinimumHeight(35);
    t1.getRow(1).setMinimumHeight(35);

still not working..

Comment: The code is all garbled up here, do you have 2 rows? `getRow(0)` edits the first row in the table, so `getRow(1)` should be for the 2nd table row

Comment: Yes I do. I created 1st row with appendtable([[1,2,3,4]]) and 2nd with r1.appendTableCell('a')...

Comment: Actually it works! I had problems to see row height because my borders are white. Thank you!